# Cargar un Formulario cada vez que creo un elemento

Tags: javascript, jquery, formularios

Buenas, la pregunta es la siguiente. Tengo un pequeño Formulario que no es mas que un Generador de Formulario, cada vez que selecciono un componente y lo creo este se me muestra en otro DIV, este formulario otorga un ID propio random, pero cuando quiero crear otro elemento, este elemento se asigna con el mismo ID que el elemento anterior.

Mi pregunta es, si me podrían ayudar.

1) Como hago para que al momento de crear otro elemento, se agregue con otro ID.

He probado con la función de **Jquery** .load, pero por alguna razón cada vez que refresca mi form, este pierde toda su funcionalidad de **Javascript** que le permite crear los elementos, validar y entregar el ID.

¿Alguna forma de poder resolverlo? Gracias de antemano.

Aquí el Código.

La Función del Botón al rellenar el Formulario:

```
/*botón de añadir*/
$("#btn_add").on("click",function(){
    var f = $("#miCampo");
    f.append("<div class='field'><label>"+$("#nom_camp").val()+": <input placeholder='"+$("#plch").val()+"' type='"+$('#select_opc').val()+"' name='"+(galpha+"_"+$("#nom_camp").val())+"' id='"+(galpha+"_"+$("#nom_camp").val())+"' class='"+(galpha+"_"+$("#nom_camp").val())+"'></label></div>");
    plch.prop('disabled', true);
    nc.prop('disabled', true);
    nc.val("");
    plch.val("");
    $("#nom_camp").val("");
    $("#id_id").text("");
    $("#id_name").text("");
    $("#id_class").text("");
            $("#form_refresh").load(location.href + " #form"
            });
})
```

La Funcion que genera el ID aleatorio

```
/*función que genera una letra y numero de forma aleatoria*/
function generarAlphanumerico(r)
{
var arreglo = new Array();
var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*100) +1;
for(var i=65; i<=90; i++)
    {arreglo[i] = String.fromCharCode(i);}

return arreglo[Math.floor(Math.random() * (arreglo.length-65)+65)]+''+r;

}
```

Formulario:

```
<!--Área de trabajo -->
                <div class="ui stripe community vertical segment">
                    <div class="ui two column center divided very relaxed stackable grid container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="column">

                            <!-- área donde se visualizará el formulario -->
                            <form class="ui form">
                                <h4>Mi formulario</h4>
                                <div id="miCampo"></div>
                                <input type="button" value="Enviar" class="ui button" id="btn_submit_generado">
                            </form>

                            </div>

                            <div class="column" id="form_refresh">
                                <form action="" class="ui form" id="form">
                                <h4 class="ui dividing header">
                                    Seleccionar
                                </h4>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <label>Tipo de campo:</label>
                                    <select class="ui fluid dropdown" id="select_opc">
                                        <option value="0">Seleccionar</option>
                                        <option value="label">Etiqueta</option>
                                        <option value="text">Caja de texto</option>
                                        <option value="textarea">Cuadro de texto</option>
                                        <option value="checkbox">Casilla de verificaci&oacute;n</option>
                                        <option value="radio">Bot&oacute;n de radio</option>
                                        <option value="select">Desplegable</option>
                                        <option value="date">Fecha</option>
                                        <option value="number">Número</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <label>Nombre del campo</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="nom_camp">
                                </div>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <label>id: <span id="id_id"></span></label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <label>Name: <span id="id_name"></span></label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <label>Class: <span id="id_class"></span></label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <label>Placeholder:</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="plch">
                                </div>
                                <div class="ui green vertical animated button" id="btn_add" style="float:right;">
                                    <div class="hidden content">Add</div>
                                    <div class="visible content">
                                        <i class="add icon"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Muestra tu código para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: Deberías poner el código de lo que has probado

Comment: Ya agregue el Codigo, el JQuery que refresca el Form es el $("#form_refresh").load(location.href + " #form"
            });

Pero al momento de cargarlo de nuevo, pierde todas las funciones de Javascript.

Comment: Hola @KuraiDark23 , no olvides marcar la respuesta que te parezca correcta. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quiero ofrecer la solución que conseguí de seguro a alguien mas le servirá. La verdad me puse a pensar mucho en refrescar (refresh) el DIV, y nada con otra solución.

Pero consigue con una función resolver todo. Pasandole la función por jquery, para que el campo ejecutara de nuevo la función que generaba el ID.

```
/************************************************
GENERAR ID ALEATORIO AL HACER CLICK O TAB(FOCUS)
************************************************/
$("#nom_camp").on("click focus", function(){
    galpha = generarAlphanumerico();
    $("#nom_camp").off("click focus");
    console.log("El ID es: "+galpha);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Saludos, considero que esta es otra posible solución, y a lo mejor le sirve a alguien:

```
<script>
    var contador = 1;

/*botón de añadir*/
$("#btn_add").on("click",function(){
    var f = $("#miCampo");
    galpha = 'campoAdicional_'+contador;
    contador = contador+1;
......
</script>
```

La idea es tener una variable global con un valor inicial numérico, la cual nos servirá de sufijo para nombrar los id's que se irán agregando. Cada vez que se haga click para agregar, se forma el id, con un prefijo (campoAdicional_), y el valor de de la variable global. Posterior a esto, se adiciona uno (1) a la variable global; de esta forma, cuando se agregue un nuevo elemento, este tendrá un id diferente al anterior.

Espero que alguien pueda encontrar algo útil en esta solución.

Comment: Buena respuesta, recomiendo dejar de utilizar generarAlphanumerico(r), porque es demasiado y te es mas fácil el contador 1+, saludos

Comment: Gracias @chenio muy buena propuesta, como tengo por requisito pasar un Prefijo alfanumérico ejecuto el generarAlphanumerico().  (A que te refieres por demasiado? Shortys).

Answer (score 0):

Cuando lo que quiero es crear nuevos elementos pero con id diferente utilizo la función jQuery *clone()*. De esta manera puedo clonar elementos ya existentes y visibles o bien crear "plantillas" a copiar (ocultas con *display: none* o similar) que así son fácilmente editables (al ser HTML/CSS y no parte del Javascript). El código base es el siguiente:

```
$(template_id).clone(true).appendTo($(template_id).parent()).attr('id', nuevo_id);
```

Nota que añado la copia al mismo lugar en que se encuentra la original pero puedes añadirlo donde quieras cambiando el parámetro del *.appendTo()*.

Las variables son:

```
- template_id: el identificador de lo que quiero clonar (y aquí tb a donde se copia).
- nuevo_id: el nuevo id que le quiero dar a la copia.
```

A la misma línea de jQuery le puedes añadir por ejemplo `.addClass('_bloque_clonado_')`, `.fadeIn('fast')`, etc, etc... directamente, para adaptar así el clonador a cada necesidad.

En general creo que es bastante personalizable y sencillo a la vez. Espero que os sea útil.

Comment: Gracias por compartir tu idea y conocimientos Dario.

Comment: ¡Un placer! Gracias a tí por iniciar esta pregunta.